# How to create count PivotTable with several data counts

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a basic count PivotTable with a small twist.

My table looks something like the following

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Toyota | 2013 |
| Honda | 2013 |
| Toyota | 2013 |
| Honda | 2015 |
| Toyota | 2012 |
| Honda | 2014 |
| Toyota | 2016 |
| Honda | 2016 |
| Honda | 2016 |
| Honda | 2014 |

I want my PivotTable to have `x` amount of bar groups, where `x` is the number of different values in `A`, in this case, 2 (Honda, Toyota). Each group would then have `y` bars, where `y` is the number of different values in `B` for the corresponding `A` value (For Honda 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016. For Toyota 2012, 2013, 2016) and the size of each bar in each group would be the count, the amount of values in `B` for the corresponding `A` value.

Eventually I expect a graph that will represent something like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota | 2012 | 1 |
|  | 2013 | 2 |
|  | 2016 | 1 |
| Honda | 2013 | 1 |
|  | 2014 | 2 |
|  | 2015 | 1 |
|  | 2016 | 2 |

And this is how I would want the graph to look like:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add an example of what you expect

Comment: @P.b done (I eventually what a visual graph that will represent this table)

Comment: @P.b https://imgur.com/a/VYouYH9 - this is after I entered the values manually, looking to automate this for like 30k rows

Comment: Just select the data and from the `Insert`-menu select `Pivot Chart` > `PivotChart and PivotTable`. Add both the `brand` and the `year` to `Axis` and `year` to `Values`. This defaults to `Sum of year`; change it to `Count of year`. Done. Nothing special actually.